# Hyperlink for Android?

Tags: android, xml

Ok so I have seen many official apps that have "hyperlink" buttons where there is no button background, no border, no shadow, just clickable text. Just like a HTML Hyperlink.

But when you tap it, it has a ripple effect, and you can tell that it's being tapped on.

But it appears, from searching, that Android doesn't have Hyperlink components. And when I style the button - I can make it *look* like that, but I cannot get it to behave like it should. I have to set the background to transparent, otherwise a border shadow is drawn on the right-side of the button. But when the button is transparent, no ripple effect or ANY touch effect is rendered. Also, if I have just a normal button, it does not render a material-styled ripple effect when tapped, it just changes the background color.

Is there an "official" way to have a "Hyperlink" in Android apps? (with proper Marshmallow/Lollipop touch effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Linkify.addLinks() for textview,that will act as a hyperlink.then you can also change the background properties of the view